# best optimal solution for streaming rails server logs to browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am looking for a best optimal way to stream my Rails server logs over to the browser. Have tried using browser_log gem which is not working in my case.Please suggest me any such type of gem available or any optimal way to stream the logs.

I am performing a tedious  background job on my server which require  an hour or so to complete so need logs in that case to  keep a track of the job

Comment: You are asking us to recommend off-site code or solutions, but that is off-topic. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages. Instead, you need to search, try things, then when you run into a problem ask a specific question. "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)"

Comment: Hey Tin , I am not asking for off-site code. I am just trying to the best way or recommended way to get  my productions logs over the browser tried a lot of things but   they are having there limitations ...

Comment: "suggest me any such type of gem available". That's an off-site resource. You have new users of the site recommending gems, so they, wrongly, suggested gems so they got the same meaning from the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this gem  [logstasher](https://github.com/shadabahmed/logstasher)

This gem is heavily inspired from lograge, but it's focused on one thing and one thing only. That's making your logs awesome like this https://github.com/shadabahmed/logstasher#awesome-logging-for-rails-

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use [rollbar.com](http://rollbar.com)

It has a gem and browse your log in very usefull form. For example, use system and browser of user. This features you can see at https://rollbar.com/demo/demo/

For less than 5000 errors in month id free. After overflow disabled to end of month

Comment: hey man i am performing a tedious  background job on my server which need an hour or so to complete so need logs in that case to  keep a track.